# AttributeError: module 'skimage.restoration' has no attribute 'rolling_ball'

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I am working with images which require simple shading correction and found
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_rolling_ball.html

I set up a quick environment to run the sample code provided in the link which raised the attribute error. I tried the script on both my work computer and personal pc and have the same attribute error. I have version 0.17.2 installed. scikit-image modules are importing just fine.[image: script supplied by documentation for rolling_ball. I'm sure it is something simple but it's eluding me.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rolling ball was only added in version 0.18, so you need to upgrade your installed version.